# In TPL Dataflow, is it possible to change DataflowBlockOptions after block is created but before it is used?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

... and have it take effect?

I'd like to defer setting the ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.SingleProducerConstrained property until I'm ready to link the network together.  (Because, I want to separate creating the blocks, with their semantics, from linking the network together, with its semantics.)

But as far as I can tell you can only set the ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions when the block is created (e.g., for TransformBlock, TransformManyBlock, etc, you pass it in to the constructor and it is not visible otherwise).

However ... it hasn't escaped my notice that the properties have public setters.  So ... can I create the block with a placeholder instance of ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions and hold on to it so that I can later set SingleProducerConstrained=true if I desire, when linking the blocks together (and that it will take effect)?

(BTW, is there any way to tell if SingleProducerConstrained is having any effect other than measuring throughput?)

**Update:** @i3amon correctly pointed out in his answer this can't be done because dataflow blocks clone the `DataflowBlockOptions` you pass in and use that.  But I did it anyway, using internal data structures I can access via reflection and dynamic.  I put that in an answer below.

Comment: SingleProducerConstrained does have an effect, but only is specific situations. In ActionBlock for example, the action must be synchronous for it to count.

Comment: In my case I am dealing with synchronous actions.  It is a compute bound pipeline with no async operations.  A previous SO answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155085/tpl-dataflow-speedup/11156806#11156806) showed that it could really help throughput in such circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.  Using information from DotNetInside's decompile of the Dataflow assembly, for example, `TransformBlock` [here](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/TransformBlock%3CTInput%2C+TOutput%3E/4.5.20.0) (thanks @i3amon again for the link to dotnetinside.com), and the very nice `ExposedObject` package at [codeplex here](http://exposedobject.codeplex.com/) (which I learned about at [this blog post](http://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/), I did the following:

- The TPL Dataflow blocks all implement debugger visualizers via the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute, which, applied to a type, names another type to use in the Visual Studio debugger whenever the original type is to be displayed (e.g., watch window).
- Each of these `DebuggerTypeProxy`-named classes are inner classes of the dataflow block the attribute is attached to, usually named `DebugView`.  That class is always private and sealed.  It exposes lots of cool stuff about the dataflow block, including its genuine (not a copy) `DataflowBlockOptions` and also - if the block is a source block - an `ITargetBlock[]`, which can be used to trace the dataflow network from its start block after construction.
- Once you get an instance of the `DebugView` you can use `dynamic` via `ExposedObject` to get any of the properties exposed by the class - `ExposedObject` lets you take an object and use ordinary method and property syntax to access its methods and properties.
- Thus you can get the `DataflowBlockOptions` out of the dataflow block and change its `NameFormat`, and if it is an `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` (and you haven't yet hooked up the block to other blocks) you can change its `SingleProducerConstrained` value.
- However you can't use `dynamic` to find or construct the instance of the inner `DebugView` class.  You need reflection for that.  You start by getting the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute off your 
  dataflow block's type, fetch the name of the debugging class, assume it is an inner class of
  the dataflow block's type and search for it, convert it to a closed generic type, and finally
  construct an instance.
- Be fully aware that you're using undocumented code from the dataflow internals.  Use your own
  judgement about whether this is a good idea.  In my opinion, the developers of TPL Dataflow did a lot of work to support viewing these blocks in the debugger, and they'll probably keep it up.  Details may change, but, if you're doing proper error checking on your reflection and dynamic use of these types, you will be able to discover when your code stops working with a new version of TPL Dataflow.

The following code fragments probably don't compile together - they're simply cut&pasted out of my working code, from different classes, but they certainly give you the idea.  I made it work fine.  (Also, for brevity, I elided all error checking.)  (Also, I developed/tested this code with version 4.5.20.0 only of TPL dataflow, so you may have to adapt it for past - or future! - versions.)

```
// Set (change) the NameFormat of a dataflow block after construction
public void SetNameFormat(IDataflowBlock block, string nameFormat)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic debugView = block.GetInternalData(Logger);
        if (null != debugView)
        {
            var blockOptions = debugView.DataflowBlockOptions as DataflowBlockOptions;
            blockOptions.NameFormat = nameFormat;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}

// Get access to the internal data of a dataflow block via its DebugTypeProxy class
public static dynamic GetInternalData(this IDataflowBlock block)
{
    Type blockType = block.GetType();
    try
    {
        // Get the DebuggerTypeProxy attribute, which names the debug class type.
        DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute debuggerTypeProxyAttr =
            blockType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute>().Single();

        // Get the name of the debug class type
        string debuggerTypeProxyNestedClassName =
            GetNestedTypeNameFromTypeProxyName(debuggerTypeProxyAttr.ProxyTypeName);

        // Get the actual Type of the nested class type (it will be open generic)
        Type openDebuggerTypeProxyNestedClass = blockType.GetNestedType(
            debuggerTypeProxyNestedClassName,
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Close it with the actual type arguments from the outer (dataflow block) Type.
        Type debuggerTypeProxyNestedClass =
            openDebuggerTypeProxyNestedClass.CloseNestedTypeOfClosedGeneric(blockType);

        // Now create an instance of the debug class directed at the given dataflow block.
        dynamic debugView = ExposedObject.New(debuggerTypeProxyNestedClass, block);

        return debugView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}

// Given a (Type of a) (open) inner class of a generic class, return the (Type
// of the) closed inner class.
public static Type CloseNestedTypeOfClosedGeneric(
                       this Type openNestedType,
                       Type closedOuterGenericType)
{
    Type[] outerGenericTypeArguments = closedOuterGenericType.GetGenericArguments();
    Type closedNestedType = openNestedType.MakeGenericType(outerGenericTypeArguments);
    return closedNestedType;
}

// A cheesy helper to pull a type name for a nested type out of a full assembly name.
private static string GetNestedTypeNameFromTypeProxyName(string value)
{
    // Expecting it to have the following form: full assembly name, e.g.,
    // "System.Threading...FooBlock`1+NESTEDNAMEHERE, System..."
    Match m = Regex.Match(value, @"^.*`\d+[+]([_\w-[0-9]][_\w]+),.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (!m.Success)
        return null;
    else
        return m.Groups[1].Value;
}
// Added to IgorO.ExposedObjectProject.ExposedObject class to let me construct an 
// object using a constructor with an argument.
public ExposedObject {
    ...

    public static dynamic New(Type type, object arg)
    {
        return new ExposedObject(Create(type, arg));
    }

    private static object Create(Type type, object arg)
    {
        // Create instance using Activator
        object res = Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg);
        return res;

        // ... or, alternatively, this works using reflection, your choice:
        Type argType = arg.GetType();
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = GetConstructorInfo(type, argType);
        return constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { arg });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. Modifying the options after the fact won't work. The options are cloned inside the block's constructor. Changing the options later will have no effect.

You can see examples of that [here](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/ActionBlock%3CTInput%3E/4.5.20.0) and [here](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/TransformBlock%3CTInput%2C+TOutput%3E/4.5.20.0) and it's simple to verify:

```
var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    NameFormat = "bar",
};
var block = new ActionBlock<int>(_ => { }, options);

options.NameFormat = "hamster";
Console.WriteLine(block.ToString());
```

Output:

> bar

Comment: Thanks again i3amon.  In fact, just before seeing your answer I just looked at [dotnetinside.com](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/TransformBlock%3CTInput%2C+TOutput%3E/4.5.20.0) (which you taught me in your answer to my last question!) and found that it was cloned.