# TPL default constructor BufferBlock: Value of DataFlowBlockOptions

Tags: task-parallel-library, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow

If you use the default constructor to construct a TPL `BufferBlock`, are the `DataFlowBlockOptions` unbounded? In other words, what is the `BoundedCapacity` of the `BufferBlock`?

[As stated in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470508/in-tpl-dataflow-is-it-possible-to-change-dataflowblockoptions-after-block-is-cr), it's not possible to query nor change the values of the `BufferBlock` after construction.

Comment: Yes the default is `Unbounded`. You can see all the defaults [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlockOptions.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to find this out: read the [docs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) or create `BufferBlock` by yourself.

From `Introduction to TPL Dataflow`:

> The majority of the dataflow blocks included in `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` support the specification of a bounded capacity.
>
> This is the limit on the number of items the block may be storing and have in flight at any one time. By default, this value is initialized to [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.unbounded.aspx) (`-1`), meaning that there is no limit.
>
> However, a developer may explicitly specify an upper bound. If a block is already at its capacity when an additional message is offered to it, that message will be postponed.

Also, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.aspx):

> `DataflowBlockOptions` is mutable and can be configured through its properties.
> When specific configuration options are not set, the following defaults are used:
>
> - `TaskScheduler`: [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx)
> - `MaxMessagesPerTask`: [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.unbounded.aspx) (`-1`)
> - `CancellationToken`: [`CancellationToken.None`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none.aspx)
> - `BoundedCapacity`: [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.unbounded.aspx) (`-1`)
>
> Dataflow blocks capture the state of the options at their construction.
> **Subsequent changes to the provided** `DataflowBlockOptions` **instance should not affect the behavior of a dataflow block.**

You can always view private members from debugger:

[image: from debugger]

You also may try to get/set them by reflection, but this is really not recommended.