# Defining BoundedCapacity degrades performance

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, performance-testing, tpl-dataflow

**Is there any way to limit performance degradation with TPL Dataflow throttling?**

I have a complicated pipeline of components and trying to limit a memory requirements needed. I read in parallel from multiple files, components in a pipeline might do some addition reading from random part of those files, the rest of components do CPU bound operations.

I simplified a performance test-bench into these tests using a common test method.

```
private void TPLPerformaceTest(int generateNumbers,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions transformBlockOptions)
{
    var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => i, transformBlockOptions);

    var storedCount = 0;
    var generatedCount = 0;
    var store = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Interlocked.Increment(ref storedCount));

    transformBlock.LinkTo(store);
    transformBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(_ => store.Complete());

    for (int i = 0; i < generateNumbers; i++)
    {
        transformBlock.SendAsync(i).Wait(); //To ensure delivery
        Interlocked.Increment(ref generatedCount);
    }
    transformBlock.Complete();
    store.Completion.Wait();

    Assert.IsTrue(generatedCount == generateNumbers);
    Assert.IsTrue(storedCount == generateNumbers);
}
```

The first that has **no throttling**. On my CPU it takes about **12s** to complete, consumes about **800MB** of RAM and average CPU utilization is about **35%**.

```
[Test]
public void TPLPerformaceUnlimitedTest()
{
    var generateNumbers = 100_000_000;
    this.TPLPerformaceTest(generateNumbers,new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions());
}
```

Second test that just sets **BoundedCapacity to int.MaxValue**, thus does no limitation at all, takes **20-30s** to complete, consumes **2.1GB** of RAM and average CPU utilization is about **50%**. According to manual,  BoundedCapacity should be set to int.MaxValue by default, so I do not see the reason for performance degradation.

```
[Test]
[Sequential]
public void TPLPerformaceBounedCapacityTest()
{
    var generateNumbers = 100_000_000;
    this.TPLPerformaceTest(generateNumbers,new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
      { BoundedCapacity = Int32.MaxValue });
}
```

The third test limit **BoundedCapacity to generateNumbers / 1000**, ergo 100,000. It takes 60s to complete and consumes **450MB** of RAM and average CPU utilization is about **60%**.

```
[Test]
[Sequential]
public void TPLPerformaceBounedCapacityTenthTest()
{
    var generateNumbers = 100_000_000;
    this.TPLPerformaceTest(generateNumbers,new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
      { BoundedCapacity = generateNumbers / 1000 });
}
```

The fourth test limits **MaxDegreeOfParallelism to -1** which is according to the manual no limit. It consumed **27GB** of RAM and average CPU utilization was about **85%** and has not finished in **5 minutes**.

```
[Test]
[Sequential]
public void TPLPerformaceMaxDegreeOfParallelismTest()
{
    var generateNumbers = 100_000_000;
    this.TPLPerformaceTest(generateNumbers, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
      { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 });
}
```

All methods seems to affect performance really hard and do not behave due to my reasonable expectations.

Comment: Related: [TPL Dataflow Speedup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155085/tpl-dataflow-speedup)

Answer (score 9):

<strike>You're degrading the performance because of this line:</strike>

```
transformBlock.SendAsync(i).Wait(); //To ensure delivery
```

This **blocks** current thread before the delivery is done. You should switch to `await` to free the thread for other tasks to proceed:

```
await transformBlock.SendAsync(i); //To ensure delivery
```

Update:

I'm confused about your words that

> According to manual, [`BoundedCapacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity.aspx) should be set to [`int.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) by default

because this is not true, [from official documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782):

> [`BoundedCapacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity.aspx)
>   The majority of the dataflow blocks included in `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` support the specification of a bounded capacity.
>   This is the limit on the number of items the block may be storing and have in flight at any one time.
>   **By default, this value is initialized to [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604578.aspx) (`-1`), meaning that there is no limit.**

Here you can see all the default values after running this code:

```
var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
```

[image]

So second test with [`BoundedCapacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity.aspx) set to [`int.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) **does** add a limitation, which add some checks for place availability in block's buffers.

You can see similar behavior in third test, which consumes much less memory than second, but do more checks and waiting times to buffers to free the space, so it works slower, but with tiny memory to allocate.

Also, you can see on the screenshot that the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604628.aspx) is equal to `1`:

> [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604628.aspx)
>   By default, **an individual dataflow block processes only one message at a time**, queueing all not-yet-processed messages so that they may be processed when the currently processing message is completed.

After setting this parameter to `-1`, you open the Pandora's Box, because all the messages are being executed **at the same time by the same task scheduler**, [according to the documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) again:

> If set to [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604578.aspx) (`-1`), any number of messages may be processed concurrently, with the maximum automatically managed by the underlying scheduler targeted by the dataflow block.

As I can see in memory consumption, the task scheduler decides to start new threads for each message as there is no available in the thread pool, which takes about `1MB` per message, so you have a about a `27000` threads which are fighting each other to the CPU time. And as you can see, they aren't good at that.
The recommended degree of parallelism usually is a `Environment.ProcessorCount`, so if you want to speed up your **one** block, you can set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to this property. However, in more complicated scenarios this can be not always the best option, as other blocks will stop in waiting for a CPU time.

So what is your `reasonable expectations` for this?

Comment: `SendAsync` completes immediately unless you're hitting `BoundedCapacity`, so this is likely to have minimal effect in all test cases but one (and even there `BoundedCapacity` is still really high)

Comment: I do agree with @KirillShlenskiy. Because the Wait() is on the main thread, it has no effect on test performance. I tested it with await but it is completely the same.

Comment: Thank you @VMAtm for detailed explanation. I tried to google it, but I cannot find a reference to MSDN where I seen that BoundedCapacity should be set to int.MaxValue by default. Well, my expectation was that throughput limiting would not affect the performance 5 times like when I compare test 1 and 2.

Comment: @JanPluskal 30 / 12 != 5 times. For your amount of messages these checks are enough to triple the time of processing for ana async version. I think that posting will be faster than sending.